# Grouping per day

Tags: sql

I want a selection result where I get per day results. Im counting errors, and have the following non-working statement:

```
SELECT message, time, personid, count(*)
FROM errorlog
WHERE time BETWEEN TO_DATE(todays date - 10 days) AND TO_DATE(todays date) AND SUBSTR(message,0,3) = 'ERR'
GROUP BY DAY(time), personid, message
ORDER BY 4
```

When I run this it says "DAY": invalid indentifier.

Comment: Which flavour of sql are you using?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? We can guess but how hard is it to add a tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be a column name after GROUP BY.

TRY:

```
SELECT message, DAY(time) dayTime, personid, count(*)
FROM errorlog
WHERE time BETWEEN TO_DATE(todays date - 10 days) AND TO_DATE(todays date) AND SUBSTR(message,0,3) = 'ERR'
GROUP BY dayTime, personid, message
ORDER BY 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Any items in your `GROUP BY` must also be in your `SELECT`.

If you're grouping by the day, and you display `time` (which I suspect to be a datetime data type), and you have 2 records on what day, how would your result set display these two different times? It wouldn't be able to.

The following query uses `CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), time, 103)` in the `SELECT` and the `GROUP BY` meaning that a format of `dd/MM/yyyy` will be displayed in your result set, and your records will be grouped by this.

```
SELECT message, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), time, 103), personid, count(*)
FROM errorlog
WHERE time BETWEEN TO_DATE(todays date - 10 days) AND TO_DATE(todays date) AND SUBSTR(message,0,3) = 'ERR'
GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), time, 103), personid, message
ORDER BY 4
```

Answer (score -1):

SQL SERVER?

Correct this:

```
SELECT message, DAY(time) AS [DAY], personid, count(*)
```

Comment: This isn't right. I'm pretty sure `DAY()` returns an integer for the dates day of the month. Therefore for today, it would return `11`. So this will group by `11` regardless of month/year

Comment: Yes but it depends on what he want to do. I agree that full date is obvious thing in such queries.